# Sharing video in Whatspp, Messenger and Skype

Tags: ios, swift

```
        let localVideoPath = videoUrl
        let actItems: [Any] = [localVideoPath]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: actItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        activityController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am trying to share video from my app to other social app. I successfully share the video through mail, but It is giving an error when i am sending the video through Messenger, Whatsapp, Skype. Error is

> "This item can not be shared Please select different item"

Answer (score 0):

check out this might help you

```
let localVideoPath = "yourpath"
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: localVideoPath)

    let activityItems: [Any] = [videoURL]
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: it's just sharing the "check this out", but video isn't shared

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try sharing the local URL of the item you're trying to share. For example, if you'd like to share a pdf, don't try to share it's NSData or Data object, WhatsApp still does show that error for that. Instead, if you share the local URL of it, WhatsApp recognizes it and shares it well.

I must note that many apps including native Mail, Gmail, Slack, GDrive etc. do recognize the pdf if you try to share the Data object.

For example:

After downloading a PDF, bind its URL into a variable called fileURL:

```
 var fileURL = URL(string: url)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("AWESOME_PDF.pdf")
        return (fileURL!, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
```

Then you can simply share the fileURL instead:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(            
      activityItems: [fileURL!],
      applicationActivities: nil
)
```

WhatsApp will recognize the PDF.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I only want to share to the video, videos are fetched from mobile gallery